# Find duplicates in List(Of String) in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I have a `customers` List(of String) on which I am trying to find the duplicate customers.

```
If Not customers.Count = customers.Distinct.ToList.Count Then
     customers = customers.Except(customers.Distinct.ToList)
End If
```

But I get the following exception:

> ```
> InvalidCastException
> Unable to cast object of type '<ExceptIterator>d__99`1[System.String]' to type
> ```
>
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Is this the right way to find duplicates in a list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
customers = customers.GroupBy(Function(m) m) _
                 .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1) _
                 .Select(Function(g) g.Key).ToList
```

Comment: Thanks, but Except seems not removing the duplicates. Count of customers is 0 after this step. (customers.count = 581, customers.Distinct.ToList.count = 575)

Comment: @emaillenin yes, cause it's exactly what we try to do (which is not that smart, indeed). Look at my edit, maybe ?

Comment: I want to **find** the duplicates.. So subtracting the original list and the distinct list will give that.. Dont know how to subtract them..

Comment: Thanks for your good explantation @RaphaëlAlthaus

Answer (score 10):

The VB version:

```
Dim duplicates = listOfItems.GroupBy(Function(i) i)_
                            .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1)_
                            .[Select](Function(g) g.Key)
```

C#:

```
var duplicates = customers.GroupBy(x => x)
                          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                          .Select(g => g.Key);
```