# Check whether list has duplication items

Tags: vb.net

Have some custom object like below called: "WhateverObject". I use it in my list as below. I would like to check whether there are duplications of "Number" on my list. As you see below in this case we got two items where "Number" is duplicated (71). I just would like to check my list something like:

```
If input has duplication Then
...
Else
...
End If
```

Mu simple code:

```
Class WhateverObject
  Property Id as Integer
  Property Number as Integer
End Class

Dim input As New List(Of WhateverObject)
input.Add(New WhateverObject(1, 71))
input.Add(New WhateverObject(2, 80))
input.Add(New WhateverObject(3, 71))
```

So far i got this but how to get true/felse out of it (if function is correct)?:

```
Dim duplicates = input.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Number) _
                              .Where(Function(x) x.Count() > 1) _
                              .[Select](Function(x) x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicates in List(Of String) in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228818/find-duplicates-in-listof-string-in-vb-net)

Comment: @glennsl found it as well already but have no idea how toe extract true/false out of it (from duplicated variable)

Comment: The result is a list of **only** the duplicates, thus `If resultList.Count > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the duplicates

```
Dim duplicates =
    input.
    GroupBy(Function(i) i.Number).
    Where(Function(i) i.Count > 1).
    Select(Function(i) i.Key).
    ToList()
```

And the boolean

```
Dim hasDuplicates = duplicates.Count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228884/7943564:

```
Dim duplicates = input.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Number) _
                      .Where(Function(x) x.Count() > 1) _
                      .Any()
```

(Note: I don't actually know VB, but this modification is pretty basic Linq)