# C# getting specific subdirectories

Tags: c#

I've got a code for getting subdirectories. I'm getting all the folders in F: drive. I don't need all 6, the two I don't need are AppPacks and Managing. What do I need to alter in my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace File_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getSubDirectoryList(@"F:\Apps\");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue:");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void getSubDirectoryList(string workingDirectory)
        {
            string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(workingDirectory);

            foreach (string directory in directories)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(directory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The current printout I get from the directories is as follows:

F:\Apps\Managing

F:\Apps\Knowledge

F:\Apps\Project

F:\Apps\Software

F:\Apps\Administration

F:\Apps\AppPacks

Comment: AppPacks and Managing are folder too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicates in List(Of String) in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228818/find-duplicates-in-listof-string-in-vb-net)

Comment: Yes they are folders

Comment: They aren't duplicates. They're just folders I don't want to be listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void getSubDirectoryList(string workingDirectory)
    {
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(workingDirectory);

        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            string[] filter = {@"F:\Apps\AppPacks", @"F:\Apps\Managing"};
            if(directory.Contains(filter[0]) || directory.Contains(filter[1]))
            { 
                directories = directories.Where(x => x != filter[0]).ToArray();
                directories = directories.Where(x => x != filter[1]).ToArray();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(directory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to be working. It still displays both Folders when I run the console application

Comment: @Crazytraveller could you please put them in the original post. thanks.

Comment: @Crazytraveller fixed. I'm just re-saving the directory without these entries. I forgot to filter out the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\")
                                .Where(c => !(c.EndsWith("\\AppPacks") ||
                                              c.EndsWith("\\Manage")))
                                .ToArray();
```

Comment: I need to access the F: Drive not the C: Drive. when I edit it to be the F: drive the C: Drive still appears

Comment: Either changing .GetDirectories("c:\\") with .GetDirectories(" @"F:\Apps\") ?

Comment: You are wellcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for sub directory listing, better use recursion to nest down deep. Recursion has its limitation.... file system too big and you will run into stack overflow very soon.

I have a nuGet package of my own (look for NullVoidCreations.WpfHelpers in nuGet manager) which has a directory walker. This will allow you to traverse a directory and do your stuff since it doesn't rely on recursion. Here is the link to code file https://github.com/waliarubal/WpfHelpers/blob/master/WpfHelpers/DirectoryWalker.cs . I can explain you how to use it if its too complicated, just drop me a comment in here.

As far as ignoring directories goes, just use string comparison technique to ignore stuff which you don't need.